# cannot resolve symbol 'LocationServices'

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, location-services

I am trying to build an android app using android studio that uses the userlocation. I am trying to import the google play services LocationServices api, but it says it can't resolve symbol 'LocationServices'. I tried searching for an answer but I can't figure out what the problem is.

here is a picture of my error and code:
[image: code and error]

[image: new error]

[image: third error (yes I'm a rookie)]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

And in `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
```

you class must implement:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener { ...}
```

You need to OverWrite this methods:

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }
```

Here is a detail [Implementation](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/)

Comment: sorry to ask this much, but this gets me a new error. I edited the post again. I you didn't found out yet, im quite a rookie 

Comment: never mind, fixed the issue by putting abstract before the 'public class....'. Thanks so much for helping me out 

Comment: Not needed to put abstract...you need to overwrite the added methods...

Comment: In android Studio put cursor over the red line: and Press `ALT+ENTER` it will shows the error resolve technique: like...override method , import class etc suggestion will be provided..

Comment: thanks, I'll study that guide and if I encounter any unsolvable problems I'll ask again. Thanks again for your quick responses.

Comment: Great this worked for me. Just adding the location service into Gradle

Answer (score 5):

Looking at this 7 months after it was posted and got me out of a jam.

At the moment of writing, you have to update the build.gradle(Module: app) to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'`
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Your post helped me a lot and I hope this addition also helps others looking at this post in the future.